# how does icu4c transliteration parse the data files in /data/translit/*.txt

Tags: icu, transliteration

I am using icu4c for transliteration. I want to implement a transliteration lib in another language. I wonder the way how icu4c transliteration parses the data files in /data/translit/*.txt.

Using a parser combinator or other ways?
Could someone give a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the data is [CLDR transforms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-general.html#Transforms).  Please parse the CLDR data instead, ICU's internal format may change at any time. [twitter-cldr-rb](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb#transliteration) is an example of an alternate implementation of transliteration.